# How to mount a separate drive as /home

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro Linux, an Arch based system. I didn't specify my drive `/dev/sda6` as my `/home` in the setup.

So now I have a `/home` in my `/` drive.

How can I mount my `/dev/sda6` as my `/home`?

I tried editing `/etc/fstab` file and rebooting but it made no difference. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: `/dev/sda6` was not mounted after editing `/etc/fstab` and rebooting? Perhaps you should show us your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Umm … did you do a `mkfs`?  Have you run `fsck`?  Can you `mount` the filesystem manually?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `fstab`, including what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if you have directories in **/home**

then you want to copy them somewhere first.

```
Make a note of the permissions and ownership so that you
can make sure that they are the same when you move them.

Normally you will see /home permissions as 0700

# ls -lah /home
drwx------  4 user.user 4.0K Oct 11 21:58 user
```

If you need to format the partition ext4 then use:

```
    mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6
```

Then to umount the current **/home** directory mapping use:

```
    umount /home
```

You can verify by using the command **df**

use the -f switch to force if you have to. ie. **umount -f /home**

*Then when you have that done, use:*

```
    mount /dev/sda6 /home
```

Copy your directories to **/home** that you backed up.

If you have to you can use the following to set them back to what they were:

```
chown -R user.user /home/user 
chmod 0700 /home/user
```

**Now edit your fstab accordingly!**

Your new **/dev/sda6** should now map to **/home** when you reboot

if you changed the mapping in **/etc/fstab** appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Logout from your non-root user account and login as root.  You may have to switch to a text console to do this.  Make sure no other user accounts are logged in and no user-owned processes have files open under /home.  The easiest way to guarantee this is to reboot into single-user mode.

Then, as root:

- format /dev/sda6 (e.g. with `mkfs.ext4`) if it isn't already formatted.
- edit /etc/fstab to mount /dev/sda6 as /home.new
- `mount /home.new`
- `rsync -avx /home/ /home.new`

  **NOTE: the final `/` on `/home/` is required**
- `umount /home.new`
- `mv /home /home.old`
- edit /etc/fstab to mount /dev/sda6 as /home
- `mount /home`

You should now be able to login again as your non-root user.  If everything's working without problems you can safely delete `/home.old` with `sudo rm -rf /home.old`

You can revert to the way things were at any time before you delete /`home.old` simply by unmounting /home, commenting out the /dev/sda6 line in /etc/fstab, `rmdir /home`, and `mv /home.old /home`.  You will lose any changes (e.g. new or updated or deleted files) in the new (`/dev/sda6`) /home if you do this.